# Bootstrap accordeon - change the relative position to the collapsed/showed content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this sidebar built as an accordeon (bootsrap 4). I have a long-ish content that displays near the bottom of the page, and it tends to overflow at the bottom. I'd like it to show above the corresponding data-toggler.

[image: Sidebar]

In other words, when I click the .nav-item with the data-target #create, I'd like the #create div to show up above the .nav-item that toggled it, not below as is currently the case. Html:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion toggled" id="accordionSidebar">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/myapp/dashboard/">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-bolt"></i>
            <span>Foobar</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <hr class="sidebar-divider">
    <div class="sidebar-heading">
        Foobar
    </div>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#create" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="headingauxiliaries">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
        <span>Create</span>
    </a>
    <div id="create" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="create" data-parent="#accordionSidebar" style="">
        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
            <h6 class="collapse-header">New ...</h6>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/products/create">Produits</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/products/fournis/create/">Fournisseurs</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/products/fournis2/create/">Fournisseurs (autres)</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/admin_accounts/customer/create/">Client</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/contrats/create/">Contrat</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/pickings/create/">Picking</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/po/po/create/">PO</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/po/sample/create/">Sample</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/po/claim/create/">Claim</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/po/commercial/create/">PO (commercial)</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/rma/create/">RMA</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="/soumission/create/">Soumission</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
    <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
        <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
    </div>
</ul>
```